# EditText with large Spannable takes long to reflow

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a view with one large multi-line EditText the wraps its height content and is contained inside a Scrollview.  Basically it resembles a full screen text editor interface.

For this case if I load a very large styled Spannable created with SpannableStringBuilder (about 1MB in memory) than it becomes extremely slow when editing the contents of the EditText.  This occurs especially towards the middle or beginning of the document, where it seems to need to reflow more text.  If you edit the last paragraph or document end than performance is actually pretty good.

How can I make this work quicker when editing text at the beginning of the document? How can I override the default behaviour of EditText and get this running quickly without haven't to use a ListView of many EditTexts or something similar?  I'd like to keep it in one EditText to keep copy and paste simple.

I was thinking I might be able to keep the EditTexts content smaller and adjust it as I scroll  the ScrollView but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thanks